# ckeditor5 error "toolbarview-item-unavailable" on Vuejs3 and Django

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using CkEditor5 on my Vuejs3 and Django project, it works fine but I cannot use additional features, gives me error `toolbarview-item-unavailable`.

What should I do to upload pictures to my django app?

Features I got
[image: I got these features]

Features I want to get

[image: features I want to get]

```
<script>

import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            editor: ClassicEditor,
                editorData: '<p>Asosiy malumotlar</p>',
                editorConfig: {
                    // The configuration of the editor.
                    toolbar: {
                        items: [
                            'heading', '|',
                            'alignment', '|',
                            'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'underline', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
                            'link', '|',
                            'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'todoList',

                            'fontfamily', 'fontsize', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', '|',
                            'code', 'codeBlock', '|',
                            'insertTable', '|',
                            'outdent', 'indent', '|',
                            'uploadImage', 'blockQuote', '|',
                            'undo', 'redo'
                        ],
                        
                    }
                }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: could you add more information on `toolbarview-item-unavailable`, like the complete error message

Comment: Thanks, I've used Tinymce instead of Ckeditor